# Windows 10 time - not able to update

Tags: windows, automation, time

I noticed my windows 10 time was a few minutes out so i was trying to get it to change automatically.

Setting it to change automatically on the time and date screen didnt actually change anything.

I changed it to manual, changed it, turned auto back on. And while this is correct at the minute level, its still ~30-50s out which while petty still irritates me.

So I (as the administrator of the computer), went to settings => additional time and date settings => internet time => tried to change the server. But the button requires administrator privileges which apparently I do not have. The same admin privileges on the time and date page which I can access.

[Locked out of server sync](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJf7e.png)

Running CMD in admin mode to try the following.

"Go to Command Prompt and type the following commands:

Net Stop W32time
W32tm.exe /unregister
W32tm.exe /register
Net Start W32time"

[Gave the following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aDgv.png)

With the services not started.

went to services=> windows time => is set to manual and I am unable to change this to automatic as it is greyed out.

[Unable to be changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XihMu.png)

Any advice on how I can set my computer to auto sync/correct these lockouts?

Comment: Your screenshots are indicating you are not actually an Administrator.  Can you provide a screenshot that actually shows you are logged in as an Administrator?

Answer (score 1):

> *I (as the administrator of the computer), went to settings => additional time and date settings => internet time => tried to change
>   the server. But the button requires administrator privileges which
>   apparently I do not have.*

Are you on a Domain?  It appears so, and then your computer time is tied to the server.

If not on a Domain, then you should be able to adjust Internet time as the local administrator. Try restarting the machine.